# What speed should I maintain on land or in the air in order to experience the whole path of total solar eclipse?

Tags: sun, speed, moon, eclipse

What speed should I maintain on land or in the air in order to experience the total path of total solar eclipse?

And

What other factors are taken into account for calculating that speed? For e.g. the curvature of the earth? the time of the year?

Comment: I don't know any actual values; but the image I found showing the times suggests it will happen across the US over approximately 1.5 hours.  So pretty darn fast.

Comment: It depends on latitude due to the difference in transverse speed between the moon's orbital velocity and the rotation of Earth's surface at different latitudes.  The eclipse will last longer near the equator than at higher latitudes.  Regardless, the speeds range from 700 mph to over 2000 mph depending on latitude etc.  So unless you can acquire an SR-71 I doubt you will be able to follow for the entire path.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen reports of average speed about 1700 mph, so I assume these calculations are fairly accurate:

> 2410mph in Western Oregon
>   1747mph in central Nebraska
>   1462mph in Western Kentucky
>   1502mph near Charleston SC

That is from:  http://eclipse2017.org/blog/2016/11/27/how-fast-is-the-shadow-moving-across-the-us-during-the-eclipse/